# Android Broadcast when OS update is available

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, updates

I'm working on an app where it would be helpful to know if an OS update is available.  Is there any broadcast that my app can receive when an update is available, or perhaps another way to query the system about OS updates?

My current solution is to query an external web API to get the latest Android version for a given device and compare that to the installed version, but it would be nice if instead of having to periodically check I could just wait for a broadcast.

I've seen questions asking similar things about *application* updates, and one question asking about a broadcast when an OS update *finishes*, but I'm wondering if somehow I can know when the update first becomes available.  I'm hopeful that this is the case, since the device shows a notification, but I can't figure out where in Android that notification is coming from.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, i've had a look at the docs and can't seem to find anything useful there.

Comment: it's not possible , but , you can connect in your web service , and check manually .